# Does SEO optimisation count on the responsive side of a site?

Tags: seo, responsive-webdesign

I'm looking at making some SEO optimisation fixes, and at this point I'm sorting out the heading structure and keywords - H1's, H2's etc

We have a site where there are a number of similar blocks, and one is always visible, and one is hidden depending on the screen size. This is our method of making a single site responsive.

Firstly, how does this technique affect the SEO, and in general does the responsive side of a site matter at all to search engines? What I mean by this is if the site has different content depending on screen sizes, then which content would the search spider crawl?

Comment: Do you mean that multiple blocks on a page will have the same text, and that you'll show a different block based on the resolution? In this case it sounds like your concern is duplicated content on pages?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't affect SEO in a direct way, but take into account that users access to your site in many ways with very diffent resolutions. If your site is adapted to smaller or larger resolutions by scaling it through a responsive design, it'll have **better bounce rates** than not doing it.

This bounce rates are taken into account by Google, so **YES, it will definitely help SEO ranking**.

About the resolution, it depends if you're [crawled by the Mobile GoogleBot](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51478/screen-resolution-of-googlebot-mobile), or the usual GoogleBot. You can [Fetch as GoogleBot](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/158587) in your [Webmasters Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home) account to see what Google can actually see.